# Have can I have a different texture on parented objects?

Tags: shaders

[image][image]I'm new to Blender, just started  learning.

I'd like to know how to have different textures on parented objects.
I have this object parented with another object but when I apply image texture to one, the other is affected as well. I want two different textures applied separately to those two objects.

I have a peeling off effect on a flying shuriken. I wanna add origami paper texture to the object thats being peeled off, and metal texture to the shuriken.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You said 'this object', which object? Forgot to add screenshots?

Comment: Hi! thnx for the comment. I added the screenshot!

Comment: Can you add full screen?

Comment: Buddy, where's the object that is being peeled off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have them sharing the same material. In this case, you have to duplicate it or create a new one and assign to change independently.

[image]

Comment: Yes! thank you! That's it! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @YazTJ This site has the functionality to flag an answer as accepted to let people see that the problem was solved. I think that is a good way to say thank you even without writing a comment.